# android: use a view which handler in another Class

Tags: android

I would like to add a HeaderView to a ListView , but the HeaderView is handled in another  Class

view.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >
<krelve.view.Kanner
        android:id="@+id/kanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

handle class

```
public class Pic extends Activity{

    int[] imagesRes = { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c,
            R.drawable.d, R.drawable.e };
     public View getPic(){
        Kanner kanner =  (Kanner) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.pic, null).findViewById(R.id.kanner);
        kanner.setImagesRes(imagesRes);
        return kanner;


    }
}
```

the Class where the ListView in:

```
private void listAdd() {

    HashMap<String, Object> map;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("ItemImage", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        map.put("ItemTitle", "This is Title.....");
        map.put("ItemText", "This is text.....");
        mylist.add(map);
    }
    SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), mylist,
            R.layout.list_item,


            new String[] { "ItemImage", "ItemTitle", "ItemText" },


            new int[] { R.id.item_Image, R.id.item_Title, R.id.item_Text });

    //listView1.addHeaderView(mSchedule);
    listView.setAdapter(mSchedule);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup lf = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list, null);
    listView = (ListView) (lf.findViewById(R.id.list_main));
    listView.addHeaderView(new Pic().getPic());     
    listAdd();
    lf.removeAllViews();
    return listView;

}
```

ps: Kanner is a custom component
I think the mistake is
`listView.addHeaderView(new Pic().getPic());`.

but I can't solve the mistake.

Comment: Instead of creating an activity class, why don't you just move that getPic method to the class where you add the header view?

Comment: I have tried it  already, and also have mistake.  the error is about   LayoutInflater